# How to display server clock to the user using laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I have been assigned a task to display server clock to the user. I can do that using jquery, but we need to display our server clock which will be like a clock.

Like i have date format like : `2016-06-30 10:27:32` and it should be updated like a timer or a clock is running. I have search a lot on internet, but i did not get any clue.

Please suggest me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best solution is to get time/date from server and increment it via jquery/JS.

```
<?php $currentTime = getdate(); ?>
<script>
    var date = new Date(Date.UTC(<?php echo $currentTime['year'] .",".
                                        $currentTime['mon'] .",".
                                        $currentTime['mday'] .",".
                                        $currentTime['hours'] .",".
                                        $currentTime['minutes'] .",".
                                        $currentTime['seconds']; ?>));
    setInterval(function() {
        date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + 1);
        console.log((date.getHours() +':' + date.getMinutes() + ':' + date.getSeconds() ));
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Because setInterval isn't the most precise function, you should probably update your date once per minute via AJAX request.